# regex replace group with specific value

Tags: python, regex

I use python 2.7

I just try to change a group in a regex with a value:

```
import re

r = "/foo/bar/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/"
rc = re.compile(r)
#that i try to do : rc["pk"] = 42 and get the resut
print rc.groupindex
#return {'pk' : 1}
```

I need to do this because i don't know the regex, but I know that ther is a group in it.

Edit:

I want to have a result like this:

```
rc["pk"] = 42
#now rc is /foo/bar/42 because (?P<pk>[0-9]+) is replace with 42
```

Comment: it is not clear (to me at least) exactly what you want to achieve... perhaps you can explain a little more?

Comment: You need some text to match. `rc` is just a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a python programmer, but I work with regexes a great deal in a number of other systems. I believe you can use the [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function with backreferences to groups like so:

Search Pattern:

```
'(/foo/bar/)[0-9]+(/)'
```

Replacement pattern:

```
'\g<1>42\g<2>'
```

This would replace

```
'/foo/bar/17/'
```

with

```
'/foo/bar/42/'
```

This would even work where the folder names are expressions themselves:

```
'(/\w+/\w+/)\d+(/)'
```

Python also supports lookaround statements, like this:

```
'(?<=/foo/bar/)\d+(?=/)'
```

Then you just replace the match with `'42'`. (Lookarounds do not "consume" characters, so the text in `'((?<=...)'` and `'(?=...)'` would not be replaced.)